# How can I get the index of an array in DOS Assembly x86 (16-bit)?

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86-16, 16-bit, array-indexing

I would like to know how to deal with the index of an array. My objective is to get and change the value at a specific index.

My array looks like this:

```
Dots_pos    dw firstLine, firstLine+ 8, firstLine+ 16, firstLine+ 24, firstLine+ 32
            dw firstLine+ 40, firstLine+ 48, firstLine+ 56, firstLine+ 64, firstLine+ 72
            dw firstLine+ 80, firstLine+ 88, firstLine+ 96, firstLine+ 104, firstLine+ 112 
            dw firstLine+ 120, firstLine+ 168, firstLine+ 176, firstLine+ 184, firstLine+ 192
            dw firstLine+ 200, firstLine+ 208, firstLine+ 216, firstLine+ 224, firstLine+ 232
            dw firstLine+ 240, firstLine+ 248, firstLine+ 256, firstLine+ 264, firstLine+ 272
            dw firstLine+ 280, firstLine+ 288 
            ; 2nd line
            dw secondLine, secondLine+ 96, secondLine+ 120, secondLine+ 168, secondLine+ 192
            dw secondLine+ 288
            ;...
```

I didn't try a lot of things because I can't find any doc about it, especially in 16-bit.

Many thanks for considering my request.

Comment: Since each entry is 2 bytes, just add twice the index to the base address.

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want to use is one of the registers that can be used for addressing (for example `BX` or `SI`). Then you can get value at a specific index with `mov ax, [line + BX]` where BX is element index * 2 (since each element is 2 bytes long).

Alternatively you can put the starting address of line into BX, and then just add index * 2 directly to it.
Let's say index we want to get is in CX, then the code would be

```
mov bx, line
shl cx       ; CX *= 2
add bx, cx
mov ax, [bx]
```

Comment: `shl cx` as an alias for `shl cx, 1` is a not too common pattern. FASM? ETA: Twice `add bx, cx` would work as well. And in this case it would preserve the word index in `cx` which may be desirable.